# How to make a model in Laravel refering to this json file and the relationship between invetary and products?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I need to create 2 models. One for Inventory and one for products.
I have created for Inventory the model but I don't know how to create it for Products this file except the id and name has also a list of articles from which they are made with a quantity.
And how should it be the relationship between those two tables?
Please can you help me?

Comment: What is the shared key? `arid`?

Comment: Yes the  shared key is arid.

Comment: Can you help me please?

Comment: Do I have to create maybe another model(table also for quantity). Because I want to get all the products and quantity of each that is available with the current inventory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to have normalized tables :

1. inventory (arid , name , stock)
2. products (pid , pname)
3. product_detail (pid , arid , amount_of)

Comment: No need of using `pid` and `pname`, as the user will have `$product->pid` and `$product->pname` and that is not desired.

Comment: My request is that Products should have a name, price and a list of articles of which they are made from with a quantity.So in this case I have to create 3 tables Inventory ,Products and Products_detail?

Comment: @eshirvana Inventory has also the arid so how is going to be the relationship?

Comment: @Diamond to answer your first question , yes , 3 tables . product_datails table is linked with inventory and products table